# SQL Function to separate commas in column into new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I have a table that contains a column with comma separated values.  I need to separate those values into new rows.  Table looks like this :

```
ID|      DATE|Value|Feed|
 1|10-10-2014|5.00 |1,3,4
 2|10-11-2014|21.00|1
54|01-15-2015|8.24 |2,15
 1|02-22-2015|5.14 |1,3,4
```

And I need to break it out to :

```
ID|      DATE|Value|Feed|
 1|10-10-2014|5.00 |1
 1|10-10-2014|5.00 |3
 1|10-10-2014|5.00 |4
 2|10-11-2014|21.00|1
54|01-15-2015|8.24 |2
54|01-15-2015|8.24 |15
 1|02-22-2015|5.14 |1
 1|02-22-2015|5.14 |3
 1|02-22-2015|5.14 |4
```

So I believe I need a to write a table valued function but I'm having a difficult time figuring out where to start.

Any guidance would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need the ID so that you can join back to your table, but here is some help for the Split function https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/3854195

**EDIT:** (How to use a cursor to combine the results from the Split function with your source table)
I setup this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efd0f/12)

Comment: The part I seem to be having issues with is that every example I've seen shows the function being called and passed a user string.  I'm not sure how I can pass proper column into the function and have it correlate back to the proper ID?

Comment: Typically, cursors are frowned upon, but I'm not sure there is a better way.  I'll setup an example and then update my answer later.

Comment: @EmptySet that was my first time using SQL Fiddle.  Let me know if it works out for you.